# How to mention my role in Final year project in Resume

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, resume, corporate-responsibility

My final year project has been done by four of us. And everyone involved in every process in the project.

How should I mention my role in my resume? The project is on IoT. The process involves requirements gathering, development work, coding, testing, and deployment.

Comment: Is this a college project? In what part of your resume you plan to include that?

Answer (score 2):

> How should I mention my role in my resume?

It would help if you could clarify some things from your post. But, I will venture to say that **if this is a college project I do not recommend you include it as work experience** (as it is not actually work experience).

If you really want to include it, a better place to do so would be in some sort of "Relevant Projects" section on your resume. As it was a collective effort, you can put it something like: *"Co-designed, developed, tested and deployed an IoT project about [...] with other three team members."*

Also, remember to include such project **only if you are applying to a job that has something to do with IoT**, etc., otherwise it will be just noise in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you worked for a company on this project, mention it as experience.
If it is a part of your Final year project or something, keep it off the resume but casually mention during the interview